TwythonAuthError: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Could not authenticate
I want to use Twitter API for my project, but I have faced a problem, I cannot really solve. I also use twython. I Forked the Project from this: https://github.com/EnyanDai/FakeHealth
I got the following errror:"twython.exceptions.TwythonAuthError: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Could not authenticate you."
I use the Twitter Basic Plan (100$ per month).
may I have to refactor the following Keys and tokens? app_key,app_secret,oauth_token,oauth_token_secret
Did the naming change?
I would really appreciate some Help. I don't really have affinity for coding.
well because there is no free tier version for that, I upgradet to basic

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

That project was updated 4 years ago and probably isn't up-to-date with the latest changes at Twitter, now X: https://devcommunity.x.com/c/announcements/22
